# Copying a web reference to a new project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm trying to use the web service at this link: https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/getstarted.html

I'm trying to use the Rate service, I downloaded the C# sample code.

I'm bad at explaining what's going on, so I'll use images. Here's what the sample project files look like:

[image]

Everything works fine in this sample project.

I want to use it in an existing project that I have. I tried just copying over the Web References folder into my project, but my solution files look like:

[image]

My experience with web services is very limited, so I'm not sure what I need to do here to get the web reference working on my solution, and getting it working in Visual Studio is confusing.

I'm using .NET 4.0

Comment: you'll need to 'Add a Web Reference' rather than trying to copy that folder over....

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - I tried that, but it needs a URL. I looked all over the site and in the sample project, but I couldn't find a URL. Do you know where I could find that?

Answer (score 3):

Always,  if we want use service reference,`Web services` or other reference, we must add references to project.
In this case you must use `add web references`on your project and in dialog enter `web service url`
web service url really simple as url but have `.asmx` at the end

Comment: I tried that, I looked all over the site and in the sample project, but I couldn't find a service URL. Do you know where I could find that?

Comment: I don't have your web service url ;) , but must look for something like this `http://localhost:1461/ASP/MyWebService.asmx`

Answer (score 1):

You can still copy a service (or web) reference, without adding it from scratch.
You just need to:

1. copy the whole `Service Reference` folder
2. copy `<Compile>` and `<None Include>` tags from your project file (csproj) that refer to the Service Reference classes
3. open the `Reference.cs` files for each of you service reference and make sure to change your namespaces if needed
4. if you have configured your services in `app.config` copy also the `<system.serviceModel>` tag from there.

Comment: Worked perfect even in VS2022 with .net 4.6.2